# clarify biz rules for Yii's RBAC

Tags: php, yii

I wanted to try and get a clear idea on how to go about something with Yii's RBAC. I have an `item` table with `fk's` relating to the `user`. I'm using `CGridview` to give an option to `update` this DB record. And I've also started doing Access rules now.

**Item Table**

```
- id
- name
......
- user_id
```

**My access rule:**

```
$auth->createOperation('updateOwnItem', 'User can update their own item', 'return $params["user_id"] == Yii::app()->user->id;');
```

So for instance I may have a link to update the file that is:

`www.example.com/item/update/2`

**Controller**

```
    public function actionUpdate($id) {

    if(!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateOwnItem', array('user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id))) {

        throw new CHttpException(403, 'No access.');
    }

// Rest of controller
```

That always returns "no access" though.

The rest of my rules work though, can anyone spot what might be wrong here? Additionally I overwrote the `getId()` method so my user->id does return the user ID.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have solved this. Though please feel free to let me know if this wrong.

**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {

    $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'Item');

    if(!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateOwnItem', array('user_id' => $model->user_id))) {

        throw new CHttpException(403, 'No access.');
    }
```

I think I had to load the $model record and then access the column through the model.

Do let me know if this seems wrong though.